# Using a principal as the username in an Active Directory password authentication connection string in Azure SQL

Tags: sql, azure, connection-string

In Azure SQL, I have a service account principal (serviceaccount@domain.com) added to a database. I want to use that service account in a connection string that my Azure App Service uses to access the database. The ADO.NET Active Directory pasword authentication connection string is of the form:

Server=tcp:{your_servername}.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog={your_catalogname};Persist Security Info=False;User ID={your_username};Password={your_password};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Authentication="Active Directory Password";

When I add serviceaccount@domain.com as the username in the connection string, the connection is failing. It seems to think that @domain.com is a server.

How can I use a principal of the form username@domain.com in the connection string?

Comment: are you putting the username in quotes?

Comment: I have tried without quotes, with single quotes, and with double quotes. No luck.